# Xamarin HttpClient GetStringAsync doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient

First of all, I want to say that I tried perhaps all the solutions I found here and on other forums. Therefore, I am writing a question on the same topic again.

I try to get data using HttpClient, but it always ends unsuccessfully.

Code:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    GetData(_url);
}

async void GetData(string url)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

The code will always stop working at await client.GetStringAsync(url);

Console output:

```
12-30 06:12:54.298 D/Mono    ( 7828): Requesting loading reference 3 (of 6) of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app18/files/.__override__/App18.dll
12-30 06:12:54.298 D/Mono    ( 7828): Loading reference 3 of /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app18/files/.__override__/App18.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
12-30 06:12:54.298 D/Mono    ( 7828): Image addref System.Net.Http[0xeb1b6ae0] (asmctx DEFAULT) -> System.Net.Http.dll[0xc7765800]: 2
12-30 06:12:54.298 D/Mono    ( 7828): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Net.Http' (System.Net.Http.dll)
12-30 06:12:54.298 D/Mono    ( 7828): Assembly System.Net.Http[0xeb1b6ae0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
12-30 06:12:54.299 D/Mono    ( 7828): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Net.Http.dll.config'.
12-30 06:12:54.299 D/Mono    ( 7828): Assembly Ref addref App18[0xeb266640] -> System.Net.Http[0xeb1b6ae0]: 2
12-30 06:12:54.299 D/Mono    ( 7828): Requesting loading reference 0 (of 3) of System.Net.Http.dll
12-30 06:12:54.299 D/Mono    ( 7828): Loading reference 0 of System.Net.Http.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
Loaded assembly: System.Net.Http.dll [External]12-30 06:12:54.299 D/Mono    ( 7828): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xeb1b6ae0] -> mscorlib[0xeb2664c0]: 15

12-30 06:12:54.325 D/Mono    ( 7828): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
12-30 06:12:54.325 D/Mono    ( 7828): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_method_id'.
12-30 06:12:54.325 D/Mono    ( 7828): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_method_id'.
12-30 06:12:54.325 D/Mono    ( 7828): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_static_method_id'.
12-30 06:12:54.327 D/Mono    ( 7828): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
12-30 06:12:54.327 D/Mono    ( 7828): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_object_method_a'.
12-30 06:12:54.327 D/Mono    ( 7828): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_object_method_a'.
12-30 06:12:54.327 D/Mono    ( 7828): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_static_object_method_a'.
12-30 06:12:54.337 D/Mono    ( 7828): Requesting loading reference 1 (of 3) of System.Net.Http.dll
12-30 06:12:54.337 D/Mono    ( 7828): Loading reference 1 of System.Net.Http.dll asmctx DEFAULT, looking for System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
12-30 06:12:54.337 D/Mono    ( 7828): Assembly Ref addref System.Net.Http[0xeb1b6ae0] -> System[0xdfb327e0]: 3
Thread started:  #2
12-30 06:13:14.230 D/Mono    ( 7828): DllImport attempting to load: 'libmono-native.so'.
12-30 06:13:14.231 D/Mono    ( 7828): DllImport loaded library './libmono-native.so'.
12-30 06:13:14.231 D/Mono    ( 7828): DllImport searching in: 'libmono-native.so' ('./libmono-native.so').
12-30 06:13:14.231 D/Mono    ( 7828): Searching for 'SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes'.
12-30 06:13:14.231 D/Mono    ( 7828): Probing 'SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes'.
12-30 06:13:14.231 D/Mono    ( 7828): Found as 'SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes'.
12-30 06:13:14.232 D/Mono    ( 7828): DllImport searching in: 'libmono-native.so' ('./libmono-native.so').
12-30 06:13:14.232 D/Mono    ( 7828): Searching for 'SystemNative_LChflagsCanSetHiddenFlag'.
12-30 06:13:14.232 D/Mono    ( 7828): Probing 'SystemNative_LChflagsCanSetHiddenFlag'.
12-30 06:13:14.232 D/Mono    ( 7828): Found as 'SystemNative_LChflagsCanSetHiddenFlag'.
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
12-30 06:13:14.484 D/HostConnection( 7828): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdfb2fa80, tid 7881
12-30 06:13:14.486 D/HostConnection( 7828): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
12-30 06:13:14.488 W/OpenGLRenderer( 7828): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-30 06:13:14.502 D/EGL_emulation( 7828): eglCreateContext: 0xf647f3a0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
12-30 06:13:14.531 D/EGL_emulation( 7828): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf647f3a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc63371b0)
12-30 06:13:14.533 E/eglCodecCommon( 7828): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
12-30 06:13:14.533 E/eglCodecCommon( 7828): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
12-30 06:13:14.553 W/Gralloc3( 7828): mapper 3.x is not supported
12-30 06:13:14.554 D/HostConnection( 7828): createUnique: call
12-30 06:13:14.588 D/HostConnection( 7828): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xc6332a50, tid 7881
12-30 06:13:14.589 D/HostConnection( 7828): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
12-30 06:13:14.589 D/eglCodecCommon( 7828): allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
12-30 06:13:14.589 D/eglCodecCommon( 7828): allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff7ff000 size 0x2000
12-30 06:13:14.606 D/EGL_emulation( 7828): eglMakeCurrent: 0xf647f3a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xc63371b0)
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
The thread 0x5 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue.Could a browser access the URL to get response ?

Comment: Yeah, I get response via browser or postman.

Comment: are you testing connectivity from the same device/emulator that you are running your code on?  Testing connectivity from your desktop does not mean that your mobile device is able to connect.